# Way to customize POCOs and not lose changes with database refreshes

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Using EF 4.1 in MVC 3 environment. I'm also using the POCO generation tool I downloaded using NUGET.

I am looking for a way to "customize" the POCO classes with attributes for validation without losing these changes every time the database changes (and a resulting re-sync is performed).

I've tried creating abstract classes and instantiating an inherited class, but EF forces me to  create a concrete class through the EDMX file and this descendant class also becomes a generated POCO which is "refreshed" with every database sync.

I've notice the POCO's were partial classes meaning I could add members to the classes in a different file, but this approach wouldn't let me add to existing members.

While I understand that what I'm running into is a limitation of the database first approach, I suspect that there is a way to alter/customize the POCOs in a way that isnt lost with each re-fresh.

Comment: See [validation with buddy classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12066434/60108)

Comment: yes, Eranga, this is perfect. Binding a class as a "super attribute" that binds all data annotations. I didn't realize this was an option. You should add it as a formal answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 options:

1. Implement the [IValidatableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx) interface  on your partial class and provide the `Validate` method.
2. As Eranga mentions, use the `MetadataType` attribute to move the validation attributes to another class [with the same properties.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx)

Overriding `OnModelCreating` will only work for code first and isn't an option in model / database first.

Comment: took me many tries to get the Metadata to take. After hours of banging my head against a wall, I realized the namespaces were different. This is a working solution but I hope MS comes up with a better way.